# Are contents of ConfigAndLog directory safe to delete?

Tags: logs

I am looking at our CiviCRM install on disk and I notice that  `files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog` is taking up nearly 9GB with all files from 2014-2015.

Looking at them they are just plain text files which sort of look like query results.  Most are in the format `CiviCRM.<32character_string>.log.YYYYMMDDhhmm`  some are just `CiviCRM.<32character_string>.log`

Is it safe to `rm` these files or do they serve a purpose?

Answer (score 7):

The main use of those logs files is to help diagnose problems in CiviCRM.  You're unlikely to want to review problems from a few years ago so you can delete them.  The one without the datestamp is the current one and that should have the most recent timestamp.

However 9GB is a lot of log output!  It would be worth looking at the recent ones to see if there are current issues that need attention.

Comment: Thank you Aidan.   They only range from 2014-2015, nothing in the last 2 years though this is good to know are more for troubleshooting use.